# Real world applications of regressing complex numbers?

Tags: regression, application

I recently extended a linear regression software I developed to include complex variables.  It works very well but I am not familiar with how this can be used in the real world.  I scoured the web to find out but there are maybe only only two or three research papers that I am having a hard time understanding.

What are some practical applications of performing a linear regression of complex variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In radar signal processing, we use regression analysis, such as least-squares, mean-squared error, etc. on complex numbers. This is because the signal that is transmitted can be expressed as a complex exponential signal, and this signal is perturbed by noise that is distributed as either complex Gaussian or Laplacian.